# windows 10 and cygwin very slow

Tags: windows-10

I installed cygwin and virtualbox (disabled windows Hyper-V ) on win 10 (cpu i5-6500 8G ram DDR4, C drive is SSD) with MS defender. After a while, I first realize cygwin becomes very slow. It takes a long time to do any operation (vi, ls, etc). The setup program to add package is hanging. Then I also realize opening a command line from win 10 is also slow. I already add cygwin folder to windows defender's exclusion folder. All HDD health are good and reboot has no effect. CPU usage is very low, RAM usage is about half. 
I see lots of error in windows event like below:

```
Faulting application name: backgroundTaskHost.exe, version: 10.0.10586.0, time stamp: 0x5632d8f0
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.10586.306, time stamp: 0x571af331
Exception code: 0x00000004
Fault offset: 0x0000000000071f28
Faulting process id: 0x14e4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2c70d51e57796
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\system32\backgroundTaskHost.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 73146046-ecf1-4497-810f-ef6063a535de
Faulting package full name: Microsoft.WindowsStore_11701.1001.99.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Faulting package-relative application ID: App
```

any suggestion?